# Change color of prefab instances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two prefabs in my Assert; in my scene I have instances of the two prefabs. I am trying to change the color of all the instances of one prefab with a button click but what I get is that the color of all the instances of the two prefabs changes. How can I indicate the prefab to change inside a specific function? I'm guessing gameObject is referring to all the gameObjects in my scene and probably thats why all the instances change color.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class eventSensors : MonoBehaviour {


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void tempSensor() {

        print("estas en la funcuion de tempSensor");
        // this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;
        //gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.red;
   var prefab=     Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
    }
    public void lightSensor()
    {
        print("estas en la funcuion de lightSensor");
       gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.green;

    }
    //Sent to all game objects before the application is quit
    //this is called when the user stops playmode.
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        //reset all prefab color to default
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I only have a single material folder in the proyect

Comment: No need to create multiple materials: see my answer.

Comment: Suggestion: Post your question about about how you made ti work as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call for `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color` instead: `Renderer.material` returns the instance of the material instead of the shared one.

The same way you can call for `GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[i]` instead of `GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterials[i]` when your Renderer contains multiple materials.

As a side note, the `gameObject.GetComponent<>()` can be simplified to `GetComponent<>()` since your script inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: I figured it out by creating an Array to hold all the instances of the prefab, then a foreach function to iterate these instances and change there color using MeshRenderer.
`public GameObject[] getCount;
getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tempPrefabTag");
        int count;
        count = getCount.Length;
        foreach (GameObject o in getCount)
        {
            //To acces the material component use: MeshRenderer
  //change the color of each gameObject in the Prefab
            o.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red); }
    }`

Comment: Glad it helped! I edited your question to add your answer so it's easier to read than in a comment. If you feel this answer was correct please select it as the answer.